# d8: strange exception when using it from command line

Tags: android, dx, android-d8

Given i added d8.bat to my PATH, I tried to compile a folder of java classes into classes.dex using the modern tool `d8` (which replaced `dx`). However when I followed the example in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8),

```
dx *.class
```

I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 0: *.class
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.tools.r8.b.a(SourceFile:133)
        at com.android.tools.r8.b.a(SourceFile:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8Command.parse(D8Command.java:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(D8.java:4)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.w.a(SourceFile:84)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(D8.java:4)
```

It works normally when I specify an exact path to a certain class file, but I want to include a lot of files, not just one.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Your example generates 14 lines of gobble-dee-gook. `dx help` (vs. `dx --help`) generates 45 lines. Any reasonable program should generate a one line concise error for a simple typo. Ergo, d8 is not reasonable.